# C++: vector<vector<int>> iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

Just have some basic question regarding c++ iterators.

Say I have a object `vector<vector<int>> vec2d`.

```
vector<vector<int>>::iterator i, iEnd;
i = vec2d.begin();
iEnd = vec2d.end();
```

I am wondering if `i` is an iterator of an entire 1D array?

what is that `(*i) [1]` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am wondering if i is an iterator of an entire 1D array?

Well, `vec2d` is a vector of `vector<int>` and `i` is `vec2d`'s iterator. You can consider `vec2d` a *1d* vector of *1d* vector, and if so, `i` is an iterator for the entire `vec2d` (which is, as mentioned, a 1-d vector), *or* you can look at it as a *2d* vector of `ints` (which I see as less trivial option).

Notice that not all 1d vectors are the same. Even if you consider `vec2d` as a 1d vector, its a vector **OF** `vector<int>`, hence something like this little shenanigan    `i = tmp2.begin();` (from my example below)  will not compile.

Basically an iterator can iterate on a specific container type, be it a vector of ints, or vector of vectors of whatever. The distinction between 1d and 2d vectors isn't the issue, as I see it.

> what is that (*i) [1] mean?

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector< vector<int> > vec2d;

    vector<int> tmp1;
    tmp1.push_back(1);
    tmp1.push_back(2);

    vector<int> tmp2;
    tmp2.push_back(3);
    tmp2.push_back(4);

    vec2d.push_back(tmp1);
    vec2d.push_back(tmp2);

    vector< vector<int> >::iterator i, iEnd;
    i = vec2d.begin();
    iEnd = vec2d.end();

    cout << (*i)[1] << endl;        // outputs 2 (same as vec2d[0][1])
    cout << vec2d[0][1] << endl;    // outputs 2
    cout << vec2d[1][0] << endl;    // outputs 3
    cout << vec2d[1][1] << endl;    // outputs 4

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, `*i` takes you *"inside"* the container you iterate over (in your case, `vec2d`) and the `[1]` gives you the *2nd* element of that inner-container.

Notice that `*i[0] != (*i)[0]` because of operator-precedence (*in my example case it doesn't even compile*).

Answer (score 1):

`(*i)[1]` is then accessing the 2nd element of the current iterator. Assuming there is no other code, this would evaluate to the same as `vec2d[0][1]` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Because the template parameter of `vec2d` is `vector<int>`, your iterator `i` is going to dereference to `vector<int>` (a 1d array, as you say). If you are asking whether `vec2d` itself is internally one large array of contiguous memory, then no, each element of `vec2d` points to its own resources and an iterator of one vector element cannot iterate to the next. 
`(*i) [1]` is equivalent to `i[0][1]` and accesses the second into of the first vector inside `vec2d`. You could iterate over all of the integers inside `vec2d` with the following:

```
for (vector<vector<int>>::iterator i = vec2d.begin(); i != vec2d.end(); ++i) {
    for (vector<int>::iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j) {
        cout << *j; // do something with *j
    }
}
```